# Python concatinate and print line in one line and not 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, python-3.x

I am new to python. It's a very simple error. I am trying to concatenate strings to create 1 big string. For some reason, it is printing the string in 2 lines

```
    sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM DomainsCategories WHERE  DomainName=' + '\"' + domain + '\"' + ';'
    targetSqlFile.write(sqlQuery)
    targetSqlFile.write("\n")
```

The output in text file is coming like this :

```
 DELETE FROM DomainsCategories WHERE  DomainName="abc.com
 ";
```

where as I want it like this

```
 DELETE FROM DomainsCategories WHERE  DomainName="abc.com";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The problem is that the `domain` variable ends with a line break.

You can use `domain.strip()` to remedy this, but you might want to fix the error at its root.

Comment: i am already using domain.strip(). please see above the updated code

Comment: ` strip()` doesn't work in-place. You have to assign the returned value back to your variable. See ndpu's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try to strip domain variable before using it in query:

```
domain = domain.strip()
```

Comment: @user2942227 `strip` did not modify source string, you need to save returning value or you can place `domain.strip()` in string concatenation expression: ```sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM DomainsCategories WHERE  DomainName=' + '\"' + domain.strip() + '\"' + ';'```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use it like this:

```
  for domain in domainsList:
    domain.strip()
    sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM DomainsCategories WHERE  DomainName="%s";\n' % domain
    targetSqlFile.write(sqlQuery)
```

Anyway this is far more readable than php-like stuff with `string + '\"'+domain+'\"'`